# Приведение производного класса к базовому

Tags: c++, классы, наследование, типы

Почему данное приведение не возможно?

```
class Base
{
};

class A : protected Base
{
};

int main ()
{
    A a;
    Base *p;
    p = &a;

    return 0;
}
```

=>

```
1.cpp:33:4: error: ‘Base’ is an inaccessible base of ‘A’
  p = &a;
```

Comment: Потому что вы явно запретили его использовав `protected` наследование.

Comment: @VTT , т.е. чтобы некоторый указатель на производный класс можно было привести к указателю на базовый, необходимо, чтобы в  последовательности наследований было только public?

Comment: Да, чтобы такое приведение работало везде (а не только внутри самого класса и его дружественных функций) наследование должно быть только `public`.